# How do I create a For loop or function in python to create two pandas dataframes from a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a two different file paths in a list.

```
sn  = '/*.csv'

pb = '/*.csv'

file_paths = [sn, pb]

for i in range(1, file_paths):
    i = pd.read_csv(file_paths)
```

I need to create a loop or function to run through this list and create pandas dataframes with different names.

Output:

df1
df2

Comment: What's your problem? return [f'df{i + 1}', pd.read_csv(fp) for i, fp in enumerate(file_paths)]

Comment: Try with dictionary comprehension: `dfs = {os.path.basename(file): pd.read_csv(file) for file in file_paths}` then you call each frame by doing `dfs['file_name.csv']`

Comment: you probably want to create a dictionary of dataframes where the key is the filepath and the value is the dataframe.  Something like this will allow you to create as many as you need.

Comment: It sounds like this question is relevant to what you're doing (and implements what Chris recommends): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441157/python-how-to-create-a-dictionary-with-a-lot-of-dataframes-using-a-glob-glob

Comment: is `'/*.csv'` a filename or a regex to match many filename ?

Comment: '/*.csv' with glob.glob looks at the the most recently used file.

Answer (score -1):

I would read them into a list

```
df_list = [pd.read_csv(file_path) for file_path in file_paths]
```